# TSQL Try_Parse vs Try_Convert in MS Exam (culture code is n/a)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I taking a "test" test for 761 and see question which asks me what can I use if  value of field is not well defined so I need return NULL if conversion fails, no any specific type of data mentioned and  ** nothing about that culture code.  Just need return NULL and I have both `TRY_PARSE` and `TRY_CONVERT` as a choice.  They both do `**if fails then  returns NULL value**`, so I think they both valid answers, but it's single choice question and correct answer in this test is `TRY_PARSE`.  Is there any logic behind this or it's just not well constructed question.  This is some 3rd party vendor for drill test.
Tx all. M

-------------------------------------------------Q78

```
declare @FakeDate varchar(100) = '38383838', @FakeInt VARCHAR(10) = 'xyz'
SELECT try_convert(DATE, @FakeDate),try_convert(INT, @FakeInt)
SELECT try_parse(@FakeDate AS date), TRY_PARSE(@FakeInt AS INT)

(No column name)    (No column name)
NULL    NULL
(No column name)    (No column name)
NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Well, the second `try_convert` is trying to convert `@FakeInt` to a date whereas the second `try_parse` is correctly using `int`, but that is not really a question on the choice between `try_convert` and `try_parse`, rather on being able to spot stupid typos... unless you made a typo in your question to begin with.

Comment: Si, it was a typo, it was just my exploration, I corrected it. This still produce NULL if fail, So I assume there is no any rationale in this question.  Tx M!

Answer (score 2):

First of all: `TRY_CAST()`, `TRY_CONVERT()` and `TRY_PARSE()` will do quite the same without sepcifying a *culture* or a *format/style code*. This will rely on your system's settings implicitly. At least with a date/time this is a *never-do*.

In your case I'd suggest `TRY_PARSE()` out of the following reasons:

- You want to transform string-values to typed values. This process is called *parsing*.
- You can add culture/format information if you know any details in future

`CONVERT` and `CAST` are *multi-purpose* functions. You can cast anything to anything (as long as the cast works). `CAST` will use the cast-map to decide what can be casted explicitly. `CONVERT` does roughly the same, but offers more control with the style paramter. And that is one more reason against `TRY_CONVERT`:

- Converting a date should **never** be done without the third parameter!

My conclusio: It seems okay to me, that the correct answer is `TRY_PARSE` (mainly because of the needed action, which is *parsing a string*). But the question is really poor and far away from any real-world scenarios...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql)

> Use TRY_PARSE only for converting from string to date/time and number
>   types.

If the data type is not specified in your question, you need to choose the `TRY_CONVERT` function.
If the types to convert are date and numbers use `TRY_PARSE` function.

Comment: The data types are specified in the question, they are `date` and `int`.